# How to deploy an Angular2 + Webpack app on Azure?

Tags: azure, angular, webpack

I'm trying to find information online about how to deploy an angular2 with webpack app to azure, but I couldn't find anything helpful enough. I checked the start package as suggested here [How do you deploy Angular 2 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539622/how-do-you-deploy-angular-2-apps) but I also couldn't find much help there.

So, I have an angular2 app running with webpack locally. It's working perfectly locally. But how do I deploy it to Azure Web Apps?

I appreciate any help :)

Thanks!

Comment: so have you tried deploying it like an Angular2 app?

Comment: @4c74356b41 that's not something I want, I don't wanna miss all the goodies :) check the first answer for the link I provided, item 2. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to deploy an angular2 CLI-based app to azure as well, and am really looking for a step-by-step set of instructions too, but not the route you outlined (using CodeShip).  I'd simply like azure to monitor submissions and rebuild/deploy when changes occur.  I also used a template provided by Steve Sanderson that worked well, but I'd really like to go with a bare-bones Node.js-only approach for my client side without all the other stuff around it.  My ideal workflow is simple: angluarcli for scaffolding -> edit -> Checkin to github -> site gets updated.  Deployment is a struggle for me.

Comment: @DennisWard I understand your frustration, I'd like it to be as simple as Azure makes building .net projects using GitHub webhook, but it's not. What worked for me was my posted answer since that service is free, and you have other free options like circleci and many more... Anyway, sorry I can't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so I was able to get it working.
After researching I found out there are a few options to go by, mainly creating your own local prod build and uploading it and using CD/CI. I went with the latter. It took quite some time, but now it's all set I don't have to worry about it anymore...

I based myself in this tutorial http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-azure-codeship-angularcli/ by Shane Boyer but since link-only answers are discouraged I'm going to write it here.

Here's how I did it:

1. Create a branch release on GitHub (I use this one to publish)
2. Create a free account on CodeShip and import the GitHub repo
   [image]
   [image]
3. On `Configure Project` select `I want to create my custom commands` and use this code:
   [image]

> nvm install 4.1
>
> npm install angular-cli
>
> npm install

4. Then this one under Test pipeline:
   [image]

> ng serve &
>
> ng e2e
>
> ng build -prod

5. Click `Save and go to dashboard`
6. Now go to your Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/) and open/create your web app
7. Click on `Deployment Options > Choose Source > Local Git Repository`
   [image]
8. Then click on `Deployment Credentials` and insert the user/password you prefer
   [image]
9. Click on `Overview` and copy your `Git clone url`
   [image]
10. Go to `Project settings > Environment variables` and add `AZURE_REPO_URL` with the value being the git clone url you copied with the user/password (`https://username:password@site.scm.az(...).git`):
    [image]
    [image]
11. After, click on `Deployment` on the left navigation menu
12. Choose the branch you want to deploy from (in my case it was release) and click Save, then click on `Custom Script`
    [image]
13. Then customize and add this script:

> ```
> git config --global user.email "email@provider.com"
> git config --global user.name "Your name"
>
> git clone $AZURE_REPO_URL repofolder
>
> cd repofolder
>
> rm -rf *
>
> cp -rf ~/clone/dist/* .
> git add -A
> git commit --all --author "$CI_COMMITTER_NAME <$CI_COMMITTER_EMAIL>" --message "$CI_MESSAGE ($CI_BUILD_URL)"
>
> git push origin master
> ```

That was it. Now every time you push to GitHub CodeShip will build your code and every time you PR to release it will build AND publish to azure.

Thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/595213/shayne-boyer for this.