# Deploying Angular2 site on FTP server

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run my angular2 site on my portfolio site, but when I point to index.html file, all I get is Loading... and the page never loads. I've never deployed an angular2 site online before. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), you can create a build by using the command `ng build` and then upload those files located in `dist/` folder to your FTP server.

After executing `ng build`, you should see the following files in `dist/` folder.

```
C:\temp\ng2_test\dist>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\temp\ng2_test\dist

2016-11-24  10:50 AM    <DIR>          .
2016-11-24  10:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
2016-11-24  10:50 AM             5,430 favicon.ico
2016-11-24  10:50 AM               481 index.html
2016-11-24  10:50 AM             5,539 inline.bundle.js
2016-11-24  10:50 AM             5,600 inline.bundle.map
2016-11-24  10:50 AM         2,477,664 main.bundle.js
2016-11-24  10:50 AM         2,504,627 main.bundle.map
2016-11-24  10:50 AM            10,268 styles.bundle.js
2016-11-24  10:50 AM            13,940 styles.bundle.map
               8 File(s)      5,023,549 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  329,406,005,248 bytes free
```

**Version**

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 7.2.0
os: win32 x64
```

**Content of `dist/index.html`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ng2Test</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran ng build (also tried ng build -prod) and it finished putting the files in the dist folder, but when I put the dist folder on my ftp server and open the page from my site, I get loading... and it never loads. What step am I missing? Is there something I have to do after ng build?

Comment: I have added more information to my answer. Please check whether you're using the same version and having the same result.

Comment: I just figured out the issue. I noticed the file not found for all the ng build files were pointing to the root directory of my ftp server. site.com/ngbuild file is here(according to console errors)/ while they were all really located in dist so after the ng build I went into index.html in dist folder and put dist/ in front of all the script srcs and now it's rendering the app. Thanks for you input though, it still helped me by seeing your path of files in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

From the sites source below is what your HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>User Demo with JSON</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

You are not loading any Angular or JS files. That is the reason for app not working.

Comment: I searched SO for `deploy angular2 app` and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539622