# How to deploy a angular 2 project to a server using PUTTY?

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, server

I have developed an angular 2 app using Angular-CLI on my local server. I have finished my production phase, now I want to upload it on a server using Putty. I am using CentOS server.

I have done some research form [here](https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts) like installing node and npm to server but didn't get to the end results.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: take look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539622/how-do-you-deploy-angular-2-apps)

Comment: You need to be more specified in your question. 
1. Hosting in which server? your personal or some cloud?
2. Remember, putty is just an application you use to communicate with another server through some protocol, for example, using SSH, Telnet.
3. What kind of access do you have to the server. FTP, SSH or any admin control panel?

Comment: @BlueBird I am hosting it on my server which have CentOS.

Comment: If you are using putty, I assume you are using windows. So, download the WinSCP and copy the files to your CentOS Aapache dir over SFTP protocol.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can deploy under an Apache web server. you can find the all necessary work you need to do for deployment in this link

https://angular.io/guide/deployment