# Deploy Angular 5 + Nodejs Express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular5, package.json

I have an Angular 5 App.

This is what I have in my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.16",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.0",
    "sticky-kit": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

---

I created a **server.js** with these contents in it.

```
constexpress=require('express');
constapp=expres();
constpath=require('path');
 
app.us(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));
 
app.listen(process.env.PORT||8080);
 
 
//PathLocationStradegy
app.get('/'function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/index.html'));
});
 
console.log('Console Listening');
```

---

Then, I run these commands

```
heroku auth:login
Email : johndoe@outlook.com
Password : #########
heroku create iproject-demo
heroku git:remote iproject-demo
git status
git add -A
git push heroku master
```

---

## Debug

I tried running this

**⚡️  web  heroku ps**

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 998h 46m (99%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): npm start (1)
web.1: crashed 2018/01/27 14:18:58 -0500 (~ 1m ago)
```

---

## Result

everything looks good.

**Heroku Log** show Build Success.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (not-found)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       added 26 packages in 5.46s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 34.4M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://iproject-demo.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

But when I go to the app:

https://iproject-demo.herokuapp.com/

I see this

[image]

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Angular is an SPA, and so after you run `ng build` you need to have express redirect all http calls back to index.html so angular can take over

Comment: All right, so how do I fix that ? I attached my server.js already.

Comment: Does server.js really look like that? It's full of errors.

Comment: @MikaS, can you please suggest the correct one ? I'm new to this deployment. I followed this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bOJjAUXjhI

According to him, it works fine. 

I don't what elses to do, and who to trust.

Comment: @ihue I answered

Comment: I also follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171601/4480164

Comment: @MikaS - any suggestions on why I got this error ?

Comment: are you using any db connections

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I make my Angular app to deploy and work on Heroku:

1. Your `server.js` should look something like this: https://hastebin.com/zavehahide.js
2. In your `package.json`, move `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`
3. Also in your `package.json`, add `postinstall: ng build --prod` and `start: node server.js` to `scripts`

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when this error happens to me I have problems with node dependencies. Try to remove the node_modules folder, and the dist folder. From there spin everything up again, this mimics how heroku will build your project.

Answer (score 2):

In your `server.js` you need to redirect your http call to the index.

```
app.route('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.redirect(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
})
```

In the above it'll redirect any call to your index.html.

Comment: I will updated my `server.js` with your suggestion, and `now` how do redeploy my entire application ? `git push heroku master`  ?

Comment: Another question, should I remove my `app.get(...)` line ? and replace with your ?

Comment: replace yours with mine, also make sure you use `ng build` to make the dist folder and point to it. You shouldn't have to run ng serve at all

Comment: I don't I use `ng serve` at all. I think the logs is caches. I removed it since I don't want to confuse you guys.

Comment: I expect it to run `node server.js` as I add in my `package.json`

Comment: read the docs, once you fix that and run as I told you, it'll work

Comment: I read the docs, I tried `heroku logs` I saw old logs. I don't what else to do any more.

Comment: I followed this like : https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

Which I see why you got your suggestions from ?

Comment: sorry I don't know heroku stuff, but from what I've said once you got heroku working the rest should fall in place

Comment: Ok. I followed everything in that list, and I am not sure, I still get 500

Comment: It's ok, let others answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code in Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT||8080);


//Path Location Strategy
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/index.html'));
});

console.log('Console Listening');
```

For future reference -

try running `logs` command before hitting the URL.

```
$ heroku logs
```

Then check the logs for further details.

Comment: Have you shared the complete build log, cause I don't see your install script running during build process. Try rebuilding your project.

Comment: How do I rebuild ? `ng build --prod --aot` ?

Comment: Where should I do the rebuild ? local ?

Comment: I think my `heroku logs` show old logs. I asked a separate question for that here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48480640/4480164

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion for me ?

Comment: contact heroku support or ask a heroku question? As for getting your angular app to work I think I've done my part, please select best answer and best of luck with heroku

Comment: @ihue To rebuild on heroku you need to push an empty build.
    `$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger notification"`
    `$ git push heroku master`

Answer (score 1):

You will face memory exceed issue if you are gonna build prod on heroku. So free type won’t work.

So try to build in local and serve your dist files using express.

Use same command in PROC file

Heroku local or Heroku local web  : verify your changes in local

Comment: Thanks, let me try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In answer how to debug further. Run your app, then straight away login to Heroku, go to your app, then in the 'More' dropdown, click 'View Logs'. Should help you out!

I believe there is a way to view the live logs through the terminal too so you can see exactly what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@angular-devkit/build-optimizer` as a package in the package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.4.0",
    ...
}
```

This allows the post-install flag `--aot` to run. For some reason this package isn't built in anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for more simplicity, if you want to deploy the backend on heroku as api and the he front end on github and activate cross origin resource sharing on browsing computer, I am actually building such app, that is my plan otherwise if you get any good news of this way your are doing update me