# How to prevent Heroku Logs show old logs?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, angular5

I'm not sure why I lead my `heroku logs` command to this state.

It kept showing old logs.

---

I tried to fix it by attempting these :

```
heroku drains
heroku logs
```

I still see

```
app[api]: Release v1 created by user username@outlook.com                                       
app[api]: Initial release by user username@outlook.com                                          
app[api]: Release v2 created by user username@outlook.com                                       
app[api]: Enable Logplex by user username@outlook.com                                           
app[api]: Build started by user username@outlook.com                                            
app[api]: Deploy f4f63e5d by user username@outlook.com                                          
app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user username@outlook.com                                     
app[api]: Release v3 created by user username@outlook.com                                       
app[api]: Build succeeded                                                                          
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`                                           
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                              
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                              
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1                                                        
app[web.1]:                                                                                        
app[web.1]: > web@0.0.0 start /app                                                                 
app[web.1]: > ng serve --port 4202                                                                 
app[web.1]:                                                                                        
app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found                                                                   
app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh                                                                       
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                               
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT                                                                  
app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn                                                                 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! web@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --port 4202`                                       
app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT                                                                  
app[web.1]: npm ERR!                                                                               
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the web@0.0.0 start script.                                         
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T21_02_41_422Z-debug.log
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: > web@0.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > ng serve --port 4202
app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
app[web.1]: npm ERR! web@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --port 4202`
app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the web@0.0.0 start script.
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T21_02_49_807Z-debug.log
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iproject-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=eeca5cb3-605a-44b5-a0f2-34b5e9781e7e fwd="76.119.248.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=iproject-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=8ca288a0-43a5-49a6-a3f6-f5c6398035c8 fwd="76.119.248.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: > web@0.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > ng serve --port 4202
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
app[web.1]: npm ERR! web@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --port 4202`
app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the web@0.0.0 start script.
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T21_05_22_861Z-debug.log
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
⚡️  web
```

I don't why my logs kept showing that I run `ng serve --port 4202`

But this is my updated

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.16",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.0.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.1",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.0",
    "sticky-kit": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

I used to have my

```
npm start to run `"ng serve --port 4202"`
```

But now I changed it already, now I have my

```
npm start to run `"ng build --aot -prod"`
```

---

#### Try#2

I tried delete the app in heroku, and reploy, still same logs error.

---

#### Try#3

I am trying to reclone my project, and did a clean push to Heroku, and hopefully this logs will be overwritten. How can I debug this?

Comment: I am confused, are you unable to delete logs? or do you wish to disable log history?

Comment: I want to delete the logs, and see the latest logs. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sorry to have to inform you but Heroku no longer allows you to delete logs, you can read more about that [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sdruby/PYjsRDlCDFU)

your only real option to delete logs is to either wait 1 week for the log to expire or to write 1500 lines to the log, as Heroku will only store the most recent 1500 lines of the log file, as stated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits)

To learn about how to the log you can look at the Heroku decumentation on it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits)

to view the latest logs, you could either limit the number of log lines you can see by using the following command:

```
heroku logs -n 200
```

(replace 200 with the number of lines you wish to see)

or you could view the log in real time using `--tail`(or `-t`)

```
heroku logs --tail
```