# when i am reloading a nodejs and angular app hosted on heroku gives me an error

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I deploy a angular and nodejs app on heroku but after reloading that deployed app it gives me error.
please help in resolving this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sfh1.png)

Comment: did the deploy was success? [deploy-angular-5-nodejs-express-app-to-heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479575/deploy-angular-5-nodejs-express-app-to-heroku)

Comment: yaa it deploy successfully also show after display but after reloading any page it gives error